# Xtext disambiguation

Tags: range, grammar, keyword, xtext, disambiguation

Given the following grammar:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Program:
    {Range} ID '.' '.' ID
  | {Group} ID ID ID ID
;

terminal ID:
    'a' | '.'
;
```

and the following input:

```
a . . a
```

I would argue that there are two ways in which the string can be parsed: as a `Range` (the first alternative) or as a `Group` (the second alternative). When I try this in my generated IDE and inspect the Ecore model, a `Range` is instantiated.

What makes Xtext decide in favor of the `Range`?

**Edit:** specifically, I'm wondering why the [Xtext grammar](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/v2.8.0/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext/src/org/eclipse/xtext/Xtext.xtext) itself is not ambiguous, since a range `'a'..'z'` can be parsed as either a `Group` of `Keyword, Wildcard, Wildcard, Keyword` or as a `CharacterRange` of `Keyword, Keyword`.

Comment: the thing is that your grammar is ambigous on lexer side. the '.' of ID will never match

Comment: I don't fully understand. If the '.' of ID will never match, then what makes the lexer decide to match 'a'?

Comment: all keywords are lexer rules as well => you have two terminal rules. terminal FULL_STOP_KEYWORD: '.' and your terminal ID: 'a' | '.'; the lexer is stateless. only one rule can win

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If only one rule can win, then why does the FULL_STOP_KEYWORD rule win in this case?

Comment: cause keywords always win over other terminals

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks! If you add this as an answer to the question (instead of a comment) I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keywords become Lexer Rules a well. Thus you have two Lexer Rules

```
terminal FULL_STOP_KEYWORD: '.' ;
```

and

```
terminal ID: 'a' | '.';
```

The Lexer is not stateful. Only one rule can win. Thus '.' will always be lexed as Keyword and never as ID